# Auto complete search function in wordpress keeps populating all job titles in Database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, search, autocomplete

i just started developing website and i new to wordpress,php,mysql,jquery, hopefully someone can kind enough to help me solve the below problem which i have tried to resolve for months, thank you

- Objective:To enable users to type in job title in a search box and search box would auto populate similar job titles from database in drop down just like google search
- Problem: Search bar Drop down keep populating all job titles in Database table regardless of what text typed in search bar
- Environment: Custom page on Wordpress,XAMPP,php,html,MYSQL database name 'jobsdatabase'
- Developer's programming competency: Beginner, just started developing website for 5 months, have tried to solve this problem for 6 weeks

Relevant Files and location:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-admin\admin-ajax.php
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentysixteen\page_search_job_form V6.php
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentysixteen\functions.php

Following is the code for my wordpress custom search page----> page_search_job_form V6.php

```
<?php
 get_header();
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>  
           ul{  
                background-color:#eee;  
                cursor:pointer;  
           }  
           li{  
                padding:12px;  
           }  
    </style>  
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function()
        {  
            jQuery('#searchform_jobtitle').keyup(ajaxsubmit);
            function ajaxsubmit()
            {
                var searchform_jobtitle = jQuery(this).val();
                if (searchform_jobtitle.length >= 3)
                {
                    jQuery.ajax({ 
                                url:'/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',  
                                method:"POST",  
                                data:{'action':'searchform_jobtitle'},  
                                success:function(data) 
                                {
                                    console.log(data);
                                    jQuery("#jobtitle").fadeIn();  
                                    jQuery("#jobtitle").html(data); 
                                },
                                error:function(errorThrown)
                                {
                                    console(errorThrown);
                                }  
                                });  
                }
            }
           jQuery(document).on('click', 'li', function(){  
           jQuery('#searchform_jobtitle').val(jQuery(this).text());  
           jQuery('#jobtitle').fadeOut();  
            });  
        });

</script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <form action="/" form type="post" id="searchform_jobtitle1" style="width:500px;">
            <input type="text" id="searchform_jobtitle" name="s" placeholder="Search...">
        </form>
        <div id="jobtitle"></div>
    </body>  
 </html>
```

Following is the code that i included in wordpress function.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_searchform_jobtitle','searchform_jobtitle');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_searchform_jobtitle','searchform_jobtitle');

function searchform_jobtitle()
{

    $search_jobtitle = ucfirst($_POST["action"]);   
    $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');

    if(!$con)
    {
        echo 'Not connected to server';
        $con->print_error();
    }

    if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'jobsdb'))
    {
        echo 'Database not selected';
        $con->print_error();
    }
            if(isset($_POST["action"])) 
            {
                $output = '';  
                $query = "SELECT * FROM job_info WHERE job_title like '%".$_post["action"]."%' "; 

                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);  
                $output = '<ul class="list-unstyled">';  

      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
      {  
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
           {   
                $output .= '<li>'.$row["job_title"].'</li>'; 
           }  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           $output .= '<li>Job Not Found</li>';  
      }  

        $output.= '</ul>';  
        echo $output;  

    mysqli_close($con);
 die();

}   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've chosen a complex feature for a beginner!

Where to start troubleshooting this? Start with this line of php:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM job_info WHERE job_title like '%".$_post["action"]."%' ";
```

1. I think `$_post` should be uppercase `$_POST`.

2. I know you have a browser side limit suppressing AJAX requests when the user hasn't pushed more than three letters. But put that same limit in your php program. If your `action` variable is empty you'll get this query; I think that's why you get all the rows of your table back in the autocomplete.

```
SELECT * FROM job_info WHERE job_title like '%%'
```

3. What if your user types `junk'; DROP TABLE job_info; -- '` into your search box? In that case the SQL that gets executed will be

```
SELECT * FROM job_info WHERE job_title like '%junk'; DROP TABLE job_info; --'%'
```

It seems unlikely that's what you want. That's called SQL injection. You need to deal with it before your project goes live on the internet.

Comment: Hi Jones, thank you for your reply. As per your advice, i have changed the SQL select to :

Comment: Hi Jones, thank you for your reply. As per your advice, i have changed the SQL select to :     $query = "SELECT * FROM job_info WHERE job_title like '%".$_POST["action"]."%' "; but the outcome is the drop down keep showing 'Job Not Found', please help as i am stuck at this function for almost 5 months now, thank you